# CLI ImageMagick resize (downscale only)

Tags: resize, imagemagick

I would like to resize (only if neccessary) an image to maximum resolution of 800x600. So let's say we have image of resolution 2000x1600 and it will resize to 750x600, but if I have an image of resolution 400x300 it will leave as it is. In other words I need ImageMagick to resize images without upscaling. How can I do this?

`convert -resize 800x600 input output` does downscale but also upscale.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved it: `convert -resize 800x600\> input output` will resize only if width is larger than 800px OR height is larger than 600px.

Comment: The above won't work on Windows, you will need to use convert -resize '800x600^>' input output

Comment: This also works for Windows if you want to ignore the height (and therefore keep proportions correct) `mogrify -resize 800^> input output`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to resize the current file try `mogrify -resize 800x600\> *.jpg`
this will resize all jpg images with **more than** 800 pixels width **or** 600 height.

Comment: I tried the command, and also images smaller than the given size (here 800x600) changed in _filesize_. they became a little bit smaller. do you know why this could be? (for example 16449 --> 15975)